# dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow giving silly answers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

So this is the code i've got:

```
NSDate *myCustomDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
NSLog(@"My custom date: %@", myCustomDate);
```

And it returns: `My custom date: 0023-01-23 18:37:17 +0000`.

Why is it giving a silly answer for the year, instead of 2011? Everything else is correct.

Comment: I just tried the code, and it seems to be working fine:  My custom date: 2011-01-23 19:45:19 +0100. May be something wrong in the TimeZone settings ?

Comment: What does [NSDate date] print?

Comment: It works perfectly now. The problem was that for some reason my calendar was set to Japanese.

Comment: could you mark fluchtpunkts answer as accepted? so that people can see by one blink that your question is solved?

Answer (score 5):

Your device is using the japanese calendar.

Goto settings/International/Calendar and change back to gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting.. I copied that code exactly and got `My custom date: 2011-01-23 18:44:14 +0000`, which looks correct. Perhaps your calendar is off? What do you get when you do this?

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"My date: %@", myDate);
NSDate *myCustomDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]; 
NSLog(@"My custom date: %@", myCustomDate);
```